# Drawing custom rounded rectangle UIBezierPath on UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I have a `UIView` added. And i have a class this `UIView`.

I want to draw a rounded rectangle `UIBezierPath` in it, but does this means i have to override the drawRect for `UIView` in my class?

I wand draw this:

[image]

But i now how draw simple rounded rectangle, in my class `UIView` i added this func:

```
func roundRect()
{

let rectWidth:CGFloat = 100
let rectHeight:CGFloat = 80

let xf:CGFloat = (self.frame.width  - rectWidth)  / 2
let yf:CGFloat = (self.frame.height - rectHeight) / 2

let ctx: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
ctx.saveGState()

let rect = CGRect(x: xf, y: yf, width: rectWidth, height: rectHeight)
let clipPath: CGPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: rectCornerRadius).cgPath

ctx.addPath(clipPath)

ctx.closePath()
ctx.fillPath()
ctx.restoreGState()
}
```

Comment: Depending on your exact specifications, making an image with resizableImageWithCapInsets, or using a CAShapeLayer may be a better solution then overriding drawRect.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way to draw simple shapes in a view is to add a `CAShapeLayer` to the view. You can either add it as a sublayer of the view's layer, or you can override the view's `layerClass()` method to return `CAShapeLayer` as the class of the view's backing layer. You'd then install the path you want drawn into the layer's path property in the view's `layoutSubviews()` method